# Azure Search and Date fields

Tags: content-search, azure-search

I'm using 8.2 Update-3 with the Azure Toolkit 1.1, deployed to Web App. I've got a template with a Date field on it, and I took a search class that works with Lucene and Solr like this:

```
[IndexField("date start")]
public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
```

And the query expression:

```
DateTime time;
// ...
.Where(i => i.DateStart >= time)
.OrderBy(i => i.DateStart);
```

When I run this with Azure Search I get this exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: The constant part of the 'GreaterThanOrEqualNode' was expected to be of type 'System.DateTimeOffset', but was of type 'System.DateTime'.

So I converted my result class property and `time` variable to `DateTimeOffset`. Then I got this exception instead:

> `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException: {"error":{"code":"","message":"Invalid expression: Unsupported function call: search.ismatchscoring. This function is not supported in this API version.\r\nParameter name: $filter"}}`

And this one:

> `System.NotSupportedException: IndexFieldUtcDateTimeOffsetValueConverter cannot convert from System.DateTime.
>      at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
>      at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
>      at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Converters.CloudIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter.ReadFromIndexStorageBase(Object indexValue, String fieldName, Type destinationType)`

Am I doing date mapping wrong or is this just a limitation of the Azure Search provider or service?

Edit: found the actual search expression in App Insights:

```
ERROR Azure Search Error [Index=sitecore_web_index] 
ERROR:Error in the request URI, headers, or body Search expression:&search=language_1:(en)&$filter=not search.ismatchscoring('name__:(__Standard Values)', null, 'full', null) and date_start ge 2017-05-17T04:55:13.340Z and (templatesimplemented__/any(t:t eq '{DFFD8BFE-9C7E-4033-AD70-6C600088A9E6}')) and latestversion_1&queryType=full
```

Weirdly, the unsupported `ismatchscoring` is apparently coming from `.Where(i => i.Name != Sitecore.Constants.StandardValuesItemName)` and not the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the `ismatchscoring` error, this is the cause - apparently the default settings for Azure Search rely on an old preview version of the Azure Search API:

```
  <!--  USE ISMATCHSCORING
        Determines if Azure Search provider uses ismatchscoring() function to build complex search expressions. 
        This function is available in version 2015-02-28-Preview of Azure Search API and is not available in version 2016-09-01 or earlier versions. 
        When using Azure Search API version 2016-09-01 or earlier versions, this setting must be changed to false. 
        Changing the value to false will limit the support for complex search queries.

        Default value: true
  -->
  <setting name="ContentSearch.Azure.UseIsMatchScoring" value="true"/>
```

Changing this to false resolved that exception.

Comment: Either way, that documentation contradicts itself. Unless it was available, unavailable, and then available again ;-)